# How to change the time format (12/24 hours) of an <input>?

Tags: html

I am using HTML5 input element with `type=time`. The problem is it shows time with `12 hours` but I want it to show it in `24 hours` a day. How can I make it to 24 hours?

Here is my input field:

```html
<input type="time" name="time" placeholder="hrs:mins" pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$" class="inputs time" required>
```

Comment: Open bug on Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263320. Please vote :)

Comment: Open bug on Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425218. It indicates that: status-firefox59: --- → wontfix / status-firefox60: --- → affected / status-firefox61: --- → affected / status-firefox-esr52: --- → unaffected

Comment: @DennisHendriks and here is the solution mentioned in this bug, that solved the problem for me in Firefox: we need to set `intl.regional_prefs.use_os_locales` to true in about:config. This will follow operating system locale and also use a date like DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY depending on your settings.

Comment: @baptx Yes, I saw that. It works for me.

Comment: @DennisHendriks in fact on Linux, by using `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` in /etc/default/locale, we don't even need to set `intl.regional_prefs.use_os_locales` to true. It may be related to this Thunderbird bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907#c155

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### HTML5 Time Input

This one is the simplest of the date/time related types, allowing the user to select a time on a 24/12 hour clock, usually depending on the user's OS locale configuration. The value returned is in 24h `hours:minutes` format, which will look something like `14:30`.

More details, including the appearance for each browser, can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).

```html
<input type="time" name="time">
```

Comment: It does not work the way you are saying in latest version of chrome. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yp3b3/)

Comment: Yeah, Chrome is rendering differently.

Comment: This feature is still in draft. Each browser shows it differently.

- Opera (Presto Engine) shows it the right way.
- Chrome (Webkit Engine) shows it in AM/PM.
- Firefox (Gecko Engine) has a poor support.

Comment: I wrote a tiny component for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36758501/4640499

Comment: @JonatasWalker Looks cool buddy... But now almost all the browsers support HTML5 time component.

Comment: It baffles me that browsers still fail to implement this component properly in 2016

Comment: @PraveenKumar: In July 2016, there is still no support from Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Comment: @recursive Are they even browsers?

Comment: Edge implements `type=date / type=time` as expected.

Comment: Chrome has support for 24 hours.

Comment: @Edric Thanks but from when?

Comment: @Edric Chrome only supports 24 hours if you use a 24 hour time setting on your machine. Change your time setting and you will get an AM/PM selector. Just tested with latest version 63.

Comment: mozilla has AM/PM next to the hours

Comment: @IngusGraholskis Sure, please go ahead and update it for me. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar i m just saying. .. looking for solution to use 24hrs only.

Comment: It's amazing that after all this time and countless compilers that are able to transpile javascript and so on that we are still dealing with such a shite browser situation. Infathomable.  Try time in Safari. You can't use it unless you can be sure all your users are on the same browser.

Comment: @NorbertNorbertson I know the feel! :(

Comment: 27-08-2018 Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) with Dutch Locale... still AM/PM when using type=time

Comment: @MKZ Yes, it shows already. What exactly you are trying to say. I told **Chrome (Webkit Engine) shows it in AM/PM.**

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Well after 6 months I had hoped for a solution.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Your post not answering the question, how to create military time input that would work in all browsers...

Comment: @Playnox Appreciate your comment. It's contradicting when you say *Your post not answering the question*, while this is the **accepted answer**. Furthermore, this answer is **seven years old** and *maybe* not valid for current situation. It may have been valid long back, so I request you to rethink about your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @D.Pardal for your comment. Could you add another answer to explain further? Or better, could you suggest an edit to my post to bring it up to date? I am happy to accept it either way.

Comment: Sure. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) shows that Chrome, Opera, Firefox and the old Edge change the appearance of the time `<input>` based on the configured system locale.

Comment: @D.Pardal As this answer was written like 8 years ago and hasn't been modified since then, would you like to edit it yourself?

Comment: @D.Pardal Indeed, a lot have changed... I guess I'll update the answer by the end of this week if I find time, or please feel free to update it yourself.

Comment: It baffles me that browsers still fail to implement this component properly in **2021**.

Comment: @Avatar A lot of things goes on in here, it takes time. 

Comment: Firefox still fail to implement this properly in 2021, chrome is fine

Comment: @Catto OMG, haven't they still implemented? It's 2021!

Comment: It baffles me that browsers still fail to implement this component properly in **2023**, @Avatar

Comment: @kolypto Dayummm... It's indeed darning! 

Comment: time to get baffled in **2024**

Comment: @flen No support in 2024 yet...

Answer (score 30):

By HTML5 drafts, [`input type=time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#time-state-%28type=time%29) creates a control for time of the day input, expected to be implemented using “the user’s preferred presentation”. But this really means using a widget where time presentation follows the rules of the *browser’s locale*. So independently of the language of the surrounding content, the presentation varies by the language of the browser, the language of the underlying operating system, or the system-wide locale settings (depending on browser). For example, using a Finnish-language version of Chrome, I see the widget as using the standard 24-hour clock. Your mileage will vary.

Thus, `input type=time` are based on an idea of localization that takes it all out of the hands of the page author. This is intentional; the problem has been raised in HTML5 discussions several times, with the same outcome: no change. (Except possibly added clarifications to the text, making this behavior described as intended.)

Note that `pattern` and `placeholder` attributes are not allowed in `input type=time`. And `placeholder="hrs:mins"`, if it were implemented, would be potentially misleading. It’s quite possible that the user has to type 12.30 (with a period) and not 12:30, when the browser locale uses “.” as a separator in times.

My conclusion is that you should use `input type=text`, with `pattern` attribute and with some JavaScript that checks the input for correctness on browsers that do not support the `pattern` attribute natively.

Comment: In addition you can add a maxlength attribute and fix it to 5, you can also limit the size of the field to hint it.

Comment: The link to the HTML5 draft is now broken, try https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html instead.

Comment: My Firefox browser for some reason displays time in 12 hours format, although Windows is set to use 24 hours. And i cannot find option to change to 24 hours format. --- Very weird decision not to allow page creator to set time format, if only them know for what region they page is created.

Answer (score 12):

Its depends on your locale system time settings, make 24 hours then it will show you 24 hours time.

Comment: I can not confirm this. Running Windows 10 that shows the time in 24 hours in the notification area, but I still get an AM/PM selector on my input type="time". Tested in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: It depends on browser's locale, not systems'.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on the time format of the user's operating system *when the web browser was launched*.

So:

- If your computer's system prefs are set to use a 24-hour clock, the browser will render the `<input type="time">` element as `--:--` (time range: 00:00–23:59).
- If you change your computer's syst prefs to use 12-hour, the output won't change until you quit and relaunch the browser. Then it will change to `--:-- --` (time range: 12:00 AM – 11:59 PM).

And (as of this writing), browser support is only about 75% ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)). Yay: Edge, Chrome, Opera, Android. Boo: IE, Firefox, Safari).

Comment: I don't so, my computer works under 24h format but my chrome works with pm/am format

Comment: Same here: on Linux, my desktop is configured to 24h time format, but Chrome insists on showing AM/PM. Super annoying as no one uses AM/PM here in Sweden.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able/willing to use a tiny component I wrote this Timepicker  — https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js — for my own needs.

Usage is like this:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});

var input = document.getElementById('time');

timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 1.2em/1.3 sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#efefef, #999) fixed;
}
input {
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible yet.

Comment: Then how does this answer the question?

Comment: "How can I make it to 24 hours?" this one?

Comment: not working when we use two timepicker instance

Answer (score 1):

Support of this type is still very poor. Opera shows it in a way you want. Chrome 23 shows it with seconds and AM/PM, in 24 version (dev branch at this moment) it will rid of seconds (if possible), but no information about AM/PM.
It's not want you possibly want, but at this point the only option I see to achieve your time picker format is usage of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML provide only `input type="time"` If you are using bootstrap then you can use timepicker.
You can get code from this URL http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker
May be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Even though you see the time in HH:MM AM/PM format, on the backend it still works in 24 hour format, you can try using some basic javascript to see that.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer's system prefs are set to use a 24-hour clock, the browser will render the  element as --:-- (time range: 00:00–23:59). If you change your computer's syst prefs to use 12-hour, the output won't change until you quit and relaunch the browser.

Answer (score -3):

Simple HTML trick to get this
:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" >
                       
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4" >
                                       <label for="hours">Hours</label>
          <select class="form-control" required>
                <option>  </option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                <option value="11"> 11 </option>
                <option value="12"> 12 </option>
              </select>
             </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                      <label for="minutes">Minutes</label>
              <select class="form-control" required="">
                <option selected disabled>  </option>
                <option value="00"> 00 </option>
                <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                <option value="20"> 20 </option>
                <option value="30"> 30 </option>
                <option value="40"> 40 </option>
                <option value="50"> 50 </option>
              </select>
             </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4" >
                       <label for="hours">Select Meridiem</label>
              <select class="form-control" required="" >
                <option selected="" value="AM"> AM </option>
                <option value="PM"> PM </option>
              </select>
              </div>
             </div></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score -4):

you can try this for
html side

```
<label for="appointment-time">Choose Time</label>
<input class="form-control" type="time" ng-model="time" ng-change="ChangeTime()" />
<label class="form-control" >{{displayTime}}</label>
```

JavaScript Side

```js
function addMinutes(time/*"hh:mm"*/, minsToAdd/*"N"*/) 
{
        function z(n)
        {
           return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
        }
        var bits = time.split(':');
        var mins = bits[0]*60 + (+bits[1]) + (+minsToAdd);
        return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60); 
 }  

 $scope.ChangeTime=function()
 {
      var d = new Date($scope.time);
      var hours=d.getHours();
      var minutes=Math.round(d.getMinutes());
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      var Time=hours+':'+minutes;
      var DisplayTime=addMinutes(Time, duration);
      $scope.displayTime=Time+' - '+DisplayTime +' '+ampm;
 }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Where is the [mcve] and the mentioning of Angular?