# HTML5 changing <input type="time"> to 24hrs. format? it is possible

Tags: html, input

How to change the time format of input type time in html 5.

```
<form>
Time:<input type="time" name="timeformat"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to display it in 24 Hrs. format. Can you advice me some codes or solution for this.

Comment: Each browser that accepts this new `time` input type may render it differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours#13523302

Comment: You will need to create you own element that specifies to your needs. Probably just 2 number selectors (one that goes from 1 to 24, and another from 0 to 60).