# storing a time html5 input value

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of an html5 time input **including the AM/PM**.
using jquerys .val() outputs only the time.

JS

```
var $time = $('#start-time-dialog').val();
```

HTML

```
<input id="start-time-dialog" type="time">
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the input value

Comment: The value changes according to the user.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007037/html5-changing-input-type-time-to-24hrs-format-it-is-possible