# html5 input for timecode?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like use an html5 input field for editing video and audio timecode.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a good way to do this.  I want to display and edit:

- hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Here is what my investigation turns up thus far:

`<input type="datetime-local">` displays day, month, year, am/pm information (not needed).

[image]

`<input type="time">` does not display milliseconds information (needed) and displays am/pm information (not needed).

[image]

Do I need a custom widget?  Does one exist?  Can I modify the existing html5 widgets?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be cross-browser compliant you will need a custom widget. None of the standard input components act in this way across all browsers.

However, specifying the `step` attribute will work in Chrome:

```
<input type="time" step="00.01">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ng67n/

You can't modify the standard controls to do this, unless you use some sort of [masking plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) on a standard text input.

Comment: Thanks.  Researching how to drop am/pm from the field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007037/html5-changing-input-type-time-to-24hrs-format-it-is-possible/17007117#17007117