# How to make a time input with out am/pm

Tags: html, angularjs, time, angular-ui

I want to make an input that will allow users to add time taken. I had hoped to do this using `<input type='time">` which is pretty much exactly what I want I just don't want to have the am/pm part and I don't want it to be 24 hr either. I would like the user to be able to do something like `00:15` right up to something like `2d:40hr:10m`.

Any ideas on how I could go about this. I'm not sure if I am using the right html element.

I will also point out I am using AngualrJS and bootstrap-ui which has a time function with that is the same as the input method above so if someone has an angular way of achieving this I am open to that as well.

Comment: It may not be a good idea to use the `<input type="time"` now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007037/html5-changing-input-type-time-to-24hrs-format-it-is-possible

Comment: Good point, seems to be alot of browser compatibility variations. So how else could I do this then?

Answer (score 6):

```
<input class="without" step="1" type="time" ng-model="endTime" />

.without::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
   display: none;
 }
```

using step-1 for showing seconds field and CSS to remove am/pm field
also clear icon  and spinner is removed by using

```
 input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   margin: 0; 
 }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   margin: 0; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this fiddle. I have created a way with jquery.](http://jsfiddle.net/EPghr/)

```
<input type="time" />
<input type="button" value="Get Am or Pm" />

$("input[type='button']").on("click", function(){
    var amOrPm = "am";
    if($("input[type='time']").val().substring(0,2) < 12){
        amOrpm = "am";
    } else {
        amOrPm = "pm";   
    }

    alert($("input[type='time']").val().substring(0,2)+ amOrPm);
});
```

Comment: this is for validating and processing it into am or pm. As far as getting the am or pm to disappear from the input, i don't think that is possible.

Comment: The time input only goes up to "12" for hours, so how would you ever get a value that shows PM?

Comment: check the fiddle, the time is 24 hours format. even though it shows only to 12, when you add pm, it is now higher then 12

Comment: Not here, at least not in Chrome. Only allows me to go up to "12" for hours, so the script you provided will never generate an output of anything other than "AM."

Comment: did you look at the fiddle? i tested it in chrome and it processes fine. when you say 4:05:pm that is translated to 16:05

Comment: Oh, I see. Your script is to convert a 12-hour time to a 24-hour time, I thought you were trying to determine whether the time entered was AM or PM based on solely the numerical input.

Comment: the time input does the converting by itself, then i just check the first 2 numbers based on that theory.

Comment: This is still using am/pm when I test it but more importantly it's limited to the time span on 1day, I need to be able to do more than one day, 48hr:24m or 5d:23hr:02m. From the sounds of it. The time input isn't the right way to go as it's bound to a 24hr cycle and AM:PM. Is there another way I could get this working?

Comment: you could use a straight up input field, then just build a mask for the input.