# Input time with format 24H in Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

is there a library or some way to create an input with dart in 24H format? Currently I have an input type = "time" but shows 12H format (am / pm).

http://take.ms/ViPFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser limitation and has nothing to do with Dart.

Seems there are several browsers which don't support the `<input type="time">` at all see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime.

See also

- [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060)
- [HTML5 changing <input type="time"> to 24hrs. format? it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007037)

This page provides alternatives 
http://davidwalsh.name/html5-input-types-alternative#date

Comment: thanks. but there is a library in dart to format the date input? I do not want to add js.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Dart, this is a browser issue. I understand your caveat about JS.

Comment: For formatting and parsing dates to/from strings you can use the [DateFormat](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/0.11.10/index.html#intl/intl.DateFormat) class in the [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package.