# How to do I customize new HTML5 input types such as number, time etc.?

Tags: html

Do I have control on these fields, such that,

- I can increment and decrement the `<input type='number'>` by a number 100 instead of default 1?
- I can remove the AM/PM part for `<input type='time'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "Number" input:

```
<input type="number" step="100" min="0" max="300" />
```

`step="xxx"` where `xxx` is the amount you want to increment or decrement by. `min="yyy"` where `yyy` is the minimum value, and `max="zzz"` where `zzz` is the maxiumum value. Some handy attributes to know.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BHg5n/

#### "Time" input:

The time one varies from browser to browser, which is a shame, there aren't any attributes as of yet to control the time input consistently. I'd advise against using it.

You might want to check this question out, it explains it a little better:

[html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)