# Convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i m using html5 time attribute ;
like this

```
<input type="time" class="inputDateFromTo" id="time"  />
```

it is showing time in 24 hrs format ; but i want it in 12 hrs format with am/pm, ex "4.30 PM"

please suggest me the code using simple javascript or pattern attribute

Comment: Not an exact duplicate - but all the information you need is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours

Answer (score 1):

You can use input type as `type="datetime-local"`

```
 <input type="datetime-local" class="inputDateFromTo" id="time">
```

Comment: Didn't they removed `datetime-local`? [Reference](https://github.com/w3c/html/commit/3e5df1ee1aebed37571a23c9b62adc74a92a04b9)

Comment: i want only time not date

Comment: You can use timepicker plugin - http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples

Answer (score 0):

You can make one yourself using something like the following

```
<input type="text" required placeholder="hh:mm" pattern="\d\d?:\d\d" />
<select>
    <option selected value="am">AM</option>
    <option value="pm">PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes i know this... but is there any other way using "type='time'"