# <input type="time"> how to make 24hr format

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, tablet

Hi im trying to add a time input with ionic framework

like

```
            <label class="item item-input" name="start">
            <input type="time" ng-model="start">
        </label>
```

Put when i run it on my android tablet, i get a am/pm picker not a 24hr picker
how do i change this?

also tried using this plugin https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker
but it dosen't run well on all devices

Edit
Seams like its an device fail, works on samsung s5, but how to change this ?
[image: Samsung s5]
[image: tab 3]

Comment: i things its depends on locale settings of the device ;)

Comment: Its an samsung galxy tab3, in date and time settings time are set to 24hr

Comment: Related (if not a dupe): [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours).

Answer (score 0):

this is a device issue, and depends on the android version.