# HTML input time in 24 format

Tags: html

I am using below HTML tag:

```
<input type="time"  />
```

In Chrome, Its showing PM/AM format, can we restrict to display 24 format always.
I dont want to use HTML5 tag

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772142/24-hour-time-regex-for-html-5) post could be helpful.

Comment: It seems that `type=time` is 'still' in draft mode.
see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829783/in-different-browsers-input-time-field-shows-in-different-formats

Comment: Since it is a quite new element, and relying on different user-agent may change the result of this element, there is at my knowledge no attribute to specify format date. Instead, I find something around `max` and `min` value for this element. Maybe you should give it a try and see what happens when setting max to `24:00`. More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_max.asp)

Comment: input-time display depends on the OS setting. Only users that selected a 24h clock on their device will see it as a 24h format input. Chrome on Win10 requires restart to update time format from OS.

Comment: I'm using a machine with 24h clock and it's still showing me AM/PM which I don't want. How can I remove the AM/PM?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523302/2346893) not all browsers support the standard way. It is not a good idea to use for robust user experience. And if you use it, you cannot ask too much.

Instead use time-picker libraries. For example: [TimePicker.js](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js) is a zero dependency and lightweight library. Use it like:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

More info about the time input can be found on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: Reason for Down vote . Note : Want some Natural Answer For this question. Also it could have been done using other library but question wants natural ans without library , Please read yellow section.

Comment: hi, in your sample is there a way to prevent the user from typing other text... right now he is able to type non numeric items!

Comment: how to use it more than once, or for 2 controllers? Thanks

Comment: @Hassan The first argument for TimePicker constructor denotes the 'id' for the element to be augmented. You can use it for different ids on a single page.

Answer (score 12):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Time: <input type="time" id="myTime" value="16:32:55">

 <p>Click the button to get the time of the time field.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
     function myFunction() {
         var x = document.getElementById("myTime").value;
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
     }
 </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that by setting value field (not just what is given below) time input will be internally converted into the 24hr format.

Comment: Is it true in all browsers? Internal format is always 24 hours?

Comment: Internal format is always 24 hours, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Time_value_format)

Comment: Doesn't work in safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: In Chrome & Firefox this is presented as a "am/pm" time input control. So this answer is (no longer) working. It doesn't display/interact in a "24-hour fashion".

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with the HTML5 input type.  There are many libs available to do it, you can use momentjs or some other jQuery UI components for the best outcome.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it is taking time in AM and PM but sending data in **00-24** hours format to the server on form submit. and when use that DB data in its value then it will automatically select the appropriate **AM or PM** to edit form value.

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem desirable to have this ability, to hard-code 12 or 24 hour format as input, it's actually a bad idea. Users have preferences, typically associated with country and region.

This is why the `<input>` elements of type `time` "uses a 12- or 24-hour format for inputting times, **based on system locale**." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time))

So, actually, you don't need to worry about this (much) as the user will (likely) be provided the appropriate 12/24 format as needed (most of the time).

**To answer the question directly then, just change your system locale.**

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 with a 24 hour clock. Firefox is showing me an am/pm selector, presumably because I'm within the US. So, you know, no, I can't just trust the browser to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

To create an input field that specifically captures time in the format of (HH:MM) :

```js
function validateTimeInput(input) {
      var regex = /^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/; // Regular expression for HH:MM format
      if (!regex.test(input.value)) {
        alert("Please enter time in HH:MM .");
        input.value = ""; // Clear the input field if the format is incorrect
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Time Input (HH:MM)</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <form>
      <label for="timeInput">Choose time (HH:MM):</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timeInput" name="timeInput" 
             placeholder="HH:MM" onblur="validateTimeInput(this)" required>
      <small>Format: HH:MM (24-hour format)</small>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```