# Input type time show 12 hour format instead of 24

Tags: html, time, xampp

I have last version of chrome on both computers. I use different versions of xampp.
On 1 comp it shows 12 hour format with AM/PM and on 2-nd one 24 format. How to change on my first comp input time to 24 hours format? 
Sample:

```html
<input type="time" />
```

Comment: Check here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609407/html-input-time-in-24-format

Comment: @Apy I need normal time input in 24 hours format, not JS.

Comment: I suspect the specs do not provide a way to enforce any specific format and will just use your regional settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just changed localization to another country... very strage, but it works...

Comment: http://www.frontendwebhelp.com/html/html5-input-type-time-element/ suggests it remains different for different browsers..

Comment: The link to frontendwebhelp seems broken