# Input type time 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, html, input

Too many this type of old questions are already in Stack Overflow, but now I would like to know any new method to fix this problem!

```html
<input type="time">
```

How can we change this **12hr to 24hr** format for all browsers? It would be great this will work with **only JavaScript** and without any third party JS/Jquery. Can any one help?

**Referenced questions:**

[HTML input time in 24 format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32609407/6191987)

[html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13523060/6191987)

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time ?

Comment: yes.. but not working in Chrome!

Comment: What isn't working in chrome? I have 24hr format in chrome. The only browser which I would think isn't working is firefox with the am/pm notation

Comment: I mean I can't select 24hr time format in Chrome. If you have that could you add it an Answer?

Comment: @SuperDJ Im using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81

Comment: You don't have to select it in chrome it always is. Unless chrome looks at language/ location and changes the format according. But for me it always is 24hr

Comment: did you like to get 24 hour time without am pm from same time input fieald?

Comment: @UdaraKasun yes.. but also welcome other methods to solve.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/xcgjz9xt/

Comment: @UdaraKasun It is nice idea.. but not friendly for users, we can't type time into it that causes more mouse clicks or key press.

Answer (score -1):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Using_the_step_attribute#Time_value_format):

> The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format: "hh:mm",
>   regardless of the input format, **which is likely to be selected based
>   on the user's locale (or by the user agent)**.

So you need to change locale to get in 24hrs format.

That came to mind when I opened your same question on 2 different laptops. One is showing 24hrs format and other is showing 12hrs format.

You need to set locale in your project which has 24hrs format.

Example: `'ja-JP'`, `'en-GB'` has 24hrs format

Comment: `You need to set locale in your project which has 24hrs format.` Can you explain where I can set the locale? On document? or I can put it on `<input type="date">` it self?