# Lang attribute ignored in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-webview, lang

I'm trying to create an input time with 24 hours format, I have the following code:

```
<input type="time" step="1" lang="pl"/>
```

I tried different formats as suggested in:

[Input type time 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218179/input-type-time-24-hour-format/52224814#52224814)

But it's fully ignored:

[image: example]

I even tried to set the culture in code and it didn't work too. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no implementation, but I have a proposal open in GitHub for the WhatWG:

https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4523

You can follow it and add your comments, it will be useful and rewarding to make it happen!