# Puppeteer - How to change time input to 24 hour format?

Tags: puppeteer

How to change time input to 24-hour format? I used it for testing in Jenkins pipeline, the test misses the am/pm input. My intended user doesn't need am/pm input.

I already change the locale to my country `id` and restart the Linux server

```
LANG=id_ID.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="id_ID.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

that doesn't work,

also tried adding lang args to launch `--window-size=${width},${height} --lang=id`
doesn't work too.

It occurs when puppeteer render input with the type `time`

```
<input type="time" name="time" value="" class="form-control">
```

In my local computer, it renders

[image: in local]

in the Linux Jenkins server, I the screenshot renders

[image]

Comment: Can you more clear your question? Which and where time input to puppeteer? Or show some codes about it

Comment: @ChuongTran Okay, I updated the question, it happens when there's `time` input. It render with am/pm field I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I see in [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) **type=time** , 12 or 24-hour format depending on operating system locale.

**Check locale:**

```
$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Change locale:**

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 LANGUAGE
```

OR

```
$ sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

Do you try to change locale your server same with your local? Hope it work :)

Edited: If you don't want time format depending on the locale of the system, you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464191/5589964) (using [timepicker.js](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js))