# Textfield material ui in 24 hours format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Does anyone know what is the props to make a textfield in material ui to be 24 hour format? I cant seem to find anywhere?
here is my current component

```
                    <TextField
                      type="time"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                      name="startTime"
                      value={this.state.startTime}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086014/how-to-change-material-ui-timepicker-to-24-hour-format

Answer (score 0):

TextField meant to be used for text, use TimePicker for that purpose

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { TimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function BasicTimePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (

      <TimePicker
        clearable
        ampm={false}
        label="24 hours"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
      />
  );
}

export default BasicTimePicker;
```

Comment: okay thank you just checking thanks for help

Comment: This requires the installation of multiple additional libraries and a date framework.  Are there options that don't require all that extra stuff and change of how to handle Date objects?