# How to display AM,PM using different language in input type time?

Tags: html, localization

I have input type="time" as following:

```html
    <input type="time" id="openTime" name="openTime" value="">
```

My question is about how to change AM - PM to be displayed(localized) in another language?

Comment: why dont you use 24hour format?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the question [HTML input time in 24 format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464191/8618595) It is not a good idea to use input type time for robust user experience.

I have decided to use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) as a good alternative.

Comment: so you're saying its not natively possible to change the language?