# how to change the html input type time field to only accept like this -( 00:01:25 )

Tags: javascript, html

i wanted to input time duration in hh:mm:ss format (example - 01:23:45) in html , pls suggest me the best method. Thanks in advance

How is it possible in html ? is there any direct input type available for that ? Please help !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input time in 24 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609407/html-input-time-in-24-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default time tag in the html as below

```
 <time>10:00</time>
```

or if you want to input time using input tag and setting type to time

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go check below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Time: <input type="time" id="Time" value="01:23:45">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click to see the selected time</button>

    <p id="SeeTime"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("Time").value;
            document.getElementById("SeeTime").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```