# How to am/pm from input type time field in php?

Tags: php

I am giving a input type time in a form tag to get the particular value in php.

```
 <input class="form-control" id="timeslot" type="time" name="timeslot"  placeholder="Time" required>
```

like the above.

I want to get the time which is inserted in the input box with am/pm. Currently when i am inserting the value 12:30 pm in the input box, it is showing as 12:30 only. . Can anyone say how to get the am/pm from input type time in php ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)

Comment: hi..I dont want the am/pm to show in input field..How to do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours suggests that this particular input type is not firmly supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following carefully:

By HTML5 drafts, input type=time creates a control for time of the day input, expected to be implemented using “the user’s preferred presentation”. But this really means using a widget where time presentation follows the rules of the browser’s locale. So independently of the language of the surrounding content, the presentation varies by the language of the browser, the language of the underlying operating system, or the system-wide locale settings (depending on browser). For example, using a Finnish-language version of Chrome, I see the widget as using the standard 24-hour clock. Your mileage will vary.

Thus, input type=time are based on an idea of localization that takes it all out of the hands of the page author. This is intentional; the problem has been raised in HTML5 discussions several times, with the same outcome: no change. (Except possibly added clarifications to the text, making this behavior described as intended.)

Note that pattern and placeholder attributes are not allowed in input type=time. And placeholder="hrs:mins", if it were implemented, would be potentially misleading. It’s quite possible that the user has to type 12.30 (with a period) and not 12:30, when the browser locale uses “.” as a separator in times.

My conclusion is that you should use input type=text, with pattern attribute and with some JavaScript that checks the input for correctness on browsers that do not support the pattern attribute natively.

Thanks to user: Jukka K. Korpela

Source: [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)