# Time picker always using the 12 hours format in browser

Tags: asp.net, iis, time

I am working on an asp.net web application. I have published it using VS 2015 and deployed it under IIS6.1.
The website is hosted in a server which system time format is 24 hours.
when I start the website from IIS on a browser on the server, each time I change the time format (from 24 to 12), the input time picker input box displayed on the web page follows the system format.

```
<input type="time" id="ToTime" class="form-control">
```

However when I open the website on a chrome browser on another machine (which system time format is 24 hours as well), the time picker would always display 12 hours format.

I am not talking about the returned value from the timepicker which is always in 24 hours format, but rather about how the input time picker is displayed on the browser. I'm suspecting that the IIS overrides the system format but I can't find out how and where it might be doing so??

Comment: You might want to take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)

Comment: I have seen that thread but it is not the same problem, my problem occurs when I host the website on IIS. I have edited my question, please take a look at it.