# How to turn Jonatas Walker's TimePicker into a JS class or jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, object, timepicker

I am a fan of the timepicker from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758501/1845672) but can't get it to work in a project where `input` elements are created dynamically. Problem seems that this timepicker needs to store the object returned by the constructor. Ideally, timepicker should work like the datepicker from jQuery-UI. So I tried to be clever and before creating a jQuery plugin I tried to make a javascript class like this:

```
    function MyTimePicker(inputelement) {
        // store the timepicker object
        this.mytimepicker = new TimePicker(inputelement);
        // show picked time in the element
        this.mytimepicker.on('change', function (evt) {
            var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
            evt.element.value = value;
        });
    }
```

and use it like this on three input elements:

```
    var dummy1;
    var dummy2;
    var dummy3;
    window.onload = function () {
        dummy1 = new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time2').get(0));
        dummy2 = new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time3').get(0));
        dummy3 = new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time4').get(0));
    };
```

It doesn't work. The timepicker popup appears when clicking in each of the input elements, but the `on(change)` event is never called so that the picked time does not show in the input element.

Either because of not having enough experience with Javascript objects, or with using this timepicker.

---

Update: I improved my code with a proper prototype, here is the complete code, completely standalone to play with:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Timepicker class, standalone, by Jonatas Walker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--  source: https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758501/1845672 -->
        <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="arrayoftimes">
            <input id="time2" type="time" placeholder="Time HH:MM"><br />
            <input id="time3" type="time" placeholder="Time HH:MM"><br />
            <input id="time4" type="time" placeholder="Time HH:MM"><br />
        </div>
        <script>
            // Javascript Class. this disturbs the above reference application of TimePicker. It probably is not re-entrant.
            //constructor
            function MyTimePicker(selector) {
                this.mytimepicker;
                this.init(selector);
            }
            //prototype
            MyTimePicker.prototype = {
                init: function (selector) {
                    var inputelement = jQuery(selector).get(0);
                    this.mytimepicker = new TimePicker(inputelement);
                    // show picked time in the element
                    this.mytimepicker.on('change', function (evt) {
                        var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
                        evt.element.value = value;
                    });
                }
            };
        </script>
        <script>
            var dummy1;
            var dummy2;
            var dummy3;
            window.onload = function () {
                dummy1 = new MyTimePicker('#time2');
                dummy2 = new MyTimePicker('#time3');
                dummy3 = new MyTimePicker('#time4');
            };
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now the first input element works OK, but the picked time value goes into all three input elements. The other two inputs do show the timepicker dialog, but the picked value does not appear.

In the Firebug console, after picking the first time, I see two errors in the timepicker.js: TypeError: active is undefined.

Could that indicate that, somehow, the timepicker internal code is not re-entrant?

Or am I doing something wrong with object oriented javascript?

---

Update:

I am pretty sure that there is a bug in timepicker.js. I will report here as soon as I find it.

Comment: Does changing this: `new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time2').get(0));` to this: `new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time2')[0]);` work? Also you are not returning anything from your `MyTimePicker` so this assignment `dummy1 = new MyTimePicker(jQuery('#time2').get(0));` and the others will all contain `undefined`

Comment: @gforce301 the stuff in the window.onload works, as the timepicker popup appears. But reading on JS objects tells me that I might need to move the `this.mytimepicker.on` stuff to a `prototype`. However, as this is not really a method, this leaves me confused

Comment: It's not a bug _exactly_; `TimePicker` is expected to only be instantiated once. It expects you to pass all the `ids` of the fields you want to attach it to at the same time as an array if there are multiples. So not exactly a bug but it doesn't like being created more than once.

Comment: @gforce301 You are right! It is indeed in the docs, and I tried it. But calling the constructor a second time with a new list of id's, even with storing the return value in the same variable, did not work for me. Or is there a destructor, or something else to start over with TimePicker() ?

Comment: You're looking for [timepicker.setTarget(target)](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js#timepickersettargettarget). Looking at the docs it appears that  you can replace the elements the  timepicker is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

With gforce301 helping me to read the docs, I came to this solution to turn the timepicker into a jQuery plugin. This code has test code and is stand-alone, and contains checkboxes to select or deselect inputs for the timepicker.

The plugin is at the end of this code.

Working: you can add more inputs with the timepicker. Test this with selecting more checkboxes.

Not working: you cannot remove a timepicker from an input. If you deselect a checkbox, the related input will not be listed in the new target list passed to the `setTarget()` method, but the timepicker keeps working on the deselected input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test of Timepicker class, standalone, by Jonatas Walker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--  source: https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758501/1845672 -->
        <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .timepicker {background-color: yellow;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="arrayoftimes">
            Time 1
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="settimeclass(this, '#time1')" />
            <input id="time1" type="text" placeholder="Time HH:MM"/>
            <br />
            Time 2
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="settimeclass(this, '#time2')" />
            <input id="time2" type="text" placeholder="Time HH:MM"/>
            <br />
            Time 3
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="settimeclass(this, '#time3')" />
            <input id="time3" type="text" placeholder="Time HH:MM"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            ID's with timepicker: <span id='msg'></span>
        </div>
        <script> //this code is specific for this particular page
            // at page load, uncheck all checkboxes
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:text').val('');
            // when (un)checking a checkbox, adjust the timepicker class on each time input
            function settimeclass(self, id){
                if ($(self).prop('checked')){
                    $(id).addClass('timepicker');
                }else{
                    $(id).removeClass('timepicker');
                }
                // apply the new jquery plugin for the timepicker
                $('.timepicker').timepicker();
            }
        </script>
        <script> // this code could be moved to a library
            // jquery plugin for Jonatas's timepicker
            (function ( $ ) {
                // create time picker object
                var _timepickerobj = new TimePicker([]);//([...], {lang:'en', theme:'dark'});
                // attach event for formatting the time
                _timepickerobj.on('change', function(evt) {              
                  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
                  evt.element.value = value;
                });
                // set timepicker target to jquery selector
                $.fn.timepicker = function() {
                    var sel_array = this.toArray();
                    //_timepickerobj.target = [];// no effect
                    _timepickerobj.setTarget(sel_array);
                    // debugging: list time input id's with timepicker
                    var sel_ids = $.map(sel_array ,function(sel) {return sel.id;});
                    $('#msg').text(sel_ids);
                    return this;
                }
            }( jQuery ));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This plugin is good enough for my project, but it would be nice if someone could improve, e.g. on removing a timepicker from an input.