# Replace input box on ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following:

**JS**

```
$scope.at = {time:""};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="time" ng-model="at.time" ng-change="abc()" />
<div>{{ at.time | date: "HH:mm" }}</div>
```

Here is an example output:

```
Input: 4:10 PM
DIV:   16:10
```

My goal is to make the input also show **16:10** or whatever time in military time of whatever is eventually selected. I've tried using `ng-change` and while it does change my `div`, it does not change the value of my input box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just as a note, the time is being picked on mobile like so:
[image]

Comment: What is in the function abc()?

Comment: @RaySuelzer Nothing. Because `ng-change` doesn't work on the input box

Comment: Look into model formatters https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters. This will allow you to modify the `$viewValue` of the input while retaining the `$modelValue` of it

Comment: check this out. maybe helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523302/8303694

Comment: @JesusCarrasco this is just noting that each browser shows the time property differently. I'm looking for an angular solution to just modify the model output

Comment: Well always can do with custom directive to extend or modify viewvalue, perhaps actually input type time like the link says is still new and not all browsers support it, i think you can use also ui.timepicker from ui-bootstrap. Hope helps.