# html time field in 24 hours format

Tags: html, angular-material2

I have used **HTML input type "time"** with angular material 2.
The format of this field is based on system time format but I want to display only 24 hours formats in the time field.

How can I do that? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing code examples for better understanding.

But if I understood correctly, you need to add date pipes, as described on the  [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Example: {{dateSelected | date: 'shortTime'}}

Comment: We have time input field.  Example: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time

Here I need 24 hours format.

Comment: What is it showing on the field? Can you post your code, the result and the expected result?

Comment: It depends on the browser. Some browsers support 24 hours by default, some don't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523302/6782707

Comment: As an alternative, you can put a text field and a mask for it with it own rules