# Is there a way to make the html time input default to 12 hour clock?

Tags: html, datetime, time, timepicker

I have the following markup:

```
<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="time"class="form-control" required/>
```

In some cases, it shows the 24 hour clock and in some others the 12 hour clock. How can I make it show the 12 hour clock all the time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)

Comment: Support for this input seems to be limited still: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, 12-hour format is not currently possible:

> The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format: "hh:mm", regardless of the input format, which is likely to be selected based on the user's locale (or by the user agent).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)