# force 24 hour notation in html 5 input element of type time

Tags: html, input, time

I have been trying to use the new html5's input element of type 'time' to create a timepicker in my application.

After surfing the web about this issue for quite some time I have figured out that the time format in this input element is determined by:

- Timezone / time settings in the computer which is running the browser
- The browser itself

In some browsers I get the 12-hour notation with AM/PM displayed inside the element. Is there any way to force a 24-hour notation?

Code:

```
<input type="time"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser time settings, make 24 hours then it will show you 24 hours time.