# HTML: hide AM PM in input type time

Tags: html, css, input

I just want to show a label of type='time' without AM PM.

I tried writing this on my css:

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
  display: none;}
```

and the label looks like this:

```
<label><input type='time' value = '00:00'  name='temps[ ]'></label>
```

But it still showing anyway.

Thanks

Comment: I think there isn't a reliable cross-browser solution for this. There is a lot of posts here on SO about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours#13523302

Comment: Thanks but I already checked that answer and it led me here, trying what I tried and without working. Anyways, I got a solution changing the type and adding a couple things.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
display: none;
}
```