# Is it possible to set the limit for hours and minutes in input time drop down?

Tags: html, input, time

I am trying to submit a time duration in the hh:mm format. For that, I am using the `input type='time'` field. But on using that I see 2 issues :

a) The hours being listed from 00 to 23. Is there a way to set the limit to the range of hours shown in the drop-down and remove the `AM/PM` part of it? Say, I want to show hours only within the range 00:00 to 12:00 hours and add no limit to the minutes.

b) It always shows the current time on clicking the clock icon. Is there a way to set it to 00:00 by default?

I tried using the min and max values in the input field and I see no change after applying it. I just want to display the entry in hh:mm format with the range displayed for hours in the dropdown being 00:00 to 12:00 with no `AM/PM` part included. Or is there another alternative instead of using `time` format for the input field for this scenario?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/how-to-change-the-time-format-12-24-hours-of-an-input

Comment: Yes, I went through it. I want to show the limits 0-12 or say 0-10 regardless of the OS that is being used. But from the looks of the discussion, it seems to be an issue with the browsers?